# Central Managament Servers - List of servers

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am looking at the SSMS central management servers, I have setup a tree navigation of servers.

I would like to save this ?file? off to another location for future reference, or to pass it along to other DBAs.

Where is this ?file? located??

I looked in the registry, couldn't find anything.
I looked in the directory where SSMS is saved and didn't find anything.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\

Comment: doug, please put this as an answer so i can select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click on the server group in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and choose Export.

See [Export Registered Server Information (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/export-registered-server-information-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details.